# A drag and drop function from a bat file

Tags: batch-file, drag-and-drop

So i'm trying to launch 2 files that normally dont do anything on their own but rather need to be dragged and dropped onto the program to function, my issue being that people seem more interested in the other way around and not with launching files from a bat through a program.

So this is what it looks like I'm trying to do.

File1.pk3 + File2.wad -> Program.exe

Any help would be great

I was hoping to use a bat file to perform a drag and drop function as the .pk3 file was a level and the .wad was a moded game mode and in order to function they needed to be dropped onto the main program.

Comment: `Program.exe File1.pk3 File2.wad`

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Are you wanting to drag and drop files onto the batch file?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to drop a file onto a batch file and have the batch file do something meaningful, you can use `%1`.  It is essentially no different than executing a batch file with the "dragged" file as a parameter.

Try this:

**droponme.bat**

```
@echo off
echo Opening %1 in notepad.
echo Please close it to continue.
notepad.exe %1
echo You closed it.  Thanks!
pause
```

**helloworld.txt**

```
Hello world!
```

Try dropping `helloworld.txt` onto `droponme.bat`.  It should open the text file.
Now try running `droponme helloworld.txt` from a command line (in the same directory as the files).  You should see the exact same results.